# jQuery Slider - Getting faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, exponential

I know how to use the jQuery slider but wondered how I might go about this.

I'd like it so the further right you slide the handle the **quicker** a divs width increases.

For example. If I slide to step 1 of the slider, the width of the div continuously increases by 5px. If I slide to step 2 of the slider, the width of the div continuously increases by 10px.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
so far I have this, but this obviously isn't right. I'm not quite sure where to go from here:

```
$( ".sliderh" ).slider({
  value:1,
  min: 1,
  max: 200,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      horizontalVal = ui.value
    $('.square').css('width', horizontalVal)
  }
});
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value of the slider to increase exponentially, you just have to decide on some exponential format for it.  Something like `horizontalVal = Math.pow(horizontalVal, 2)`.  If that increases the div too slowly or too quickly, just adjust.  You could do `horizontalVal = Math.pow(horizontalVal/2, 2)` for instance.

edit:

What about something like this:

```
var increase;
var interval;

$( ".sliderh" ).slider({
  value:1,
  min: 1,
  max: 200,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      increase = ui.value;
      }
});

$(".sliderh").mousedown(function(e){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        $('.square').css('width', $('.square').width() + increase);
    }, 200);
});

$(".sliderh").mouseup(function(e){
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

You can tweak the interval length, currently set to 200ms, and the increase size, currently just set to the value of the slider, to change the effect.  Right now, it will increase while you hold down the mouse every 200ms by the value of the slider, the further you slide right, the more it increases each interval.

Comment: That partly helps, but i want the div to CONTINUALLY increase in size. So when I hold the slider halfway for example, the div will keep growing in width

edit: perhaps some form of timeout loop?

Comment: You want it to increase in size depending on how long you hold the mouse down?

Comment: Almost. It is on mouseDown but also how far your are sliding right

Comment: So, holding the mouse down increases the size, but how far right you are increases the speed? Am I getting that right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The more your slide the slider handle to the right the faster the width of a square increase.

If you only slide the slide across a little then the square width will increase slowly. If you slide the slider across to the end then the square width will increase very quickly.

The way I would describe best, is turning on a tap and the more you rotate the faster the water comes out